For a nonsingular integral symmetric matrix $S$, what are the generators of the associated orthogonal group?
For an $S$ as above, I need to know about the generators of the following group: $$O(S;\mathbb Z):= \{M\in GL_n(\mathbb Z): M^tSM=S\}.$$ We know about the generators for $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ as given in here, or here. But it seems that there is nothing about integral matrices (or about orthogonal matrices), or at least I could not find them.
I have tried to do it myself, but it is very difficult. There is a paper named "On the orthogonal groups of unimodular quadratic forms" by Wall (1962), but does not help that much in this context.
Any kind of reference or clue will be very helpful.
Thanks.

I think the best you can hope for, is an algorithm for computation of generating sets (these groups are arithmetic, hence, finitely generated and even finitely presented). Such algorithms, based on Siegel sets, are known, but impractical.

I recommend Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms. There is a chapter called Automorphs of Integral Forms. Given just a symmetric integral matrix $H,$   integer column vectors $u,v,w$ with form $f(v) = \frac{1}{2} v^t H v $  and bilinear form $\phi(u,v) = \frac{1}{2}  u^t H v.$   Given a fixed vector $w$  with $f(w) = 1,$  we get one of these automorphs by reflection in $w,$  matrix $R_w = I - w w^t H.$   He does the best looking example in dimension 3, page 301.

see my https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141284/integral-orthogonal-group-for-indefinite-ternary-quadratic-form
